# Why am I getting an EOF out of my io.PipeReader?

Tags: go

I’m using something similar in a project and I'm a bit perplexed:  why isn't anything being printed?

```
package main
import (
    "fmt"
    "encoding/json"
    "io"
)

func main() {
    m := make(map[string]string)
    m["foo"] = "bar"

    pr, pw := io.Pipe()
    go func() { pw.CloseWithError(json.NewEncoder(pw).Encode(&m)) }()

    fmt.Fscan(pr)
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/OJT1ZRAnut

Is this a race condition of some sort?  I tried removing `pw.CloseWithError` but it changes nothing.

Comment: It doesn't: https://play.golang.org/p/ec_Dbonaq4 Looks like that's not really a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for your real problem.

Comment: @kostix I guess I was unclear.  I'm not getting an EOF _error_, but nothing is being printed.  The example *does* qualify as an MCVE.  Question edited.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`fmt.Fscan`](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Fscan) takes two arguments. A reader to read from, and one or more pointers to objects to populate. Its result is `(n int, err error)`, where `n` is the number of items read, and `err` is the reason why `n` is less than the (variadic...) slice of data objects you fed into its second argument.

In this case, the slice of data objects is length zero, so `Fscan` fills zero objects and reads no data. It dutifully reports that it scanned `0` objects, and since that number is not less than the number of objects you passed into it, it reports `nil` error.

Try the following:

```
func main() {
    m := make(map[string]string)
    m["foo"] = "bar"

    pr, pw := io.Pipe()
    go func() { pw.CloseWithError(json.NewEncoder(pw).Encode(&m)) }()

    var s string
    n, err := fmt.Fscan(pr, &s)
    fmt.Println(n, err)  // should be 1 <nil>
    fmt.Println(s)       // should be {"foo":"bar"}
}
```